# How to add a column of results gotten from a method to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get a dataframe of exchange tokens as the following:

```
Exchange=df[df["marketSegment"]=="Exchange"]
Exchange
```

[image: Exchange result]

I want to add a column to the dataframe above to show each token's price.

From the following method, i can get each token's price:

```
san.get(
    "prices/huobi-token",
    from_date="2018-06-01",
    to_date="2018-06-05",
    interval="1d"
)
```

[image: san result]

Can anyone tell me how to define a function or method to quickly work out every token's price and add them together as the last column of the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use some kind of average price, you can define a function which will look up the price for a particular value of `slug`:

```
def averageprice(slug):
    pricedf = san.get(
        "prices/{}".format(slug),
        from_date="2018-06-01",
        to_date=datetime.now(),
        interval="1d"
    )

    return pricedf['priceUsd'].mean()
```

Then you can create a new column by applying that function to the original dataframe:

```
Exchange['price'] = Exchange['slug'].apply(averageprice)
```

Comment: it really took me lots of time on this question before your answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: @user1081544 No problem. Have a look at the site docs for what to do (when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: i have accepted your answer but have no privilege to upvote your answer now